# Print multiple worksheets to a single physical page

Tags: microsoft-excel, osx-lion, printing, microsoft-excel-2011

If I have three worksheets in a workbook, how can I print them on the same physical page?

On Excel for Mac 2011, doing "Print What" "Entire Workbook" gives me three different pages, even if in "Layout" I have multiple pages per sheet.

Do I have any options other than printing the three sheets to a PDF, and then printing multiple PDF pages into a single physical page?

I'm using Excel for Mac 2011, on OS X Lion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all versions of Excel, different sheets will print on different pages. If you want all content on one page, you need to consolidate it into one sheet before printing.